# Strange behaviour of rpm command on error in %pre section of a rpm package

Tags: centos, dependencies, rpm

I've got several versions of some package. The last of it has an error in %pre section that terminates the install script:

```
mypak-0.0.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm
mypak-0.0.1-2.el6.noarch.rpm
mypak-0.0.1-3.el6.noarch.rpm <-- bad package
```

All of my packages have debug output in `pre`, `post`, `preun` and `postun` sections.

I install the first package:

```
rpm -Uhv mypak-0.0.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm
```

Output (*param* is the parameter passed to script sections) is:

```
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
pre: 0.0.1-1.el6 ; param = 1
   1:mypak                  ########################################### [100%]
post: 0.0.1-1.el6 ; param = 1
```

Then I try to update my package and (accidentally) launch rpm command with all the packages at once:

```
rpm -Uhv mypak-0.0.1-*                
warning: package mypak = 0.0.1-1.el6 was already added, replacing with mypak > 0.0.1-2.el6
warning: package mypak = 0.0.1-2.el6 was already added, replacing with mypak > 0.0.1-3.el6
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
pre: 0.0.1-3.el6 ; param = 2
!!!version 3 is bad!!!
error: %pre(mypak-0.0.1-3.el6.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping mypak-0.0.1-3.el6
preun: 0.0.1-1.el6 ; param = 0
postun: 0.0.1-1.el6 ; param = 0
```

As you can see, my package was removed in the end. Moreover, the package is removed even if other packages depend on it. I don't even get any warnings about corrupted dependencies!

If I install my packages one after another, I don't have that problem. In this case installation of the third package fails and that's all. The previous version of my package is still in place.

I think this is really a strange behaviour. Is it a bug in rpm or am I missing something?

I use rpm 4.8.0 on Centos 6.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote about this behaviour to the RPM mailing list and Lubos Kardos answered that this is a bug and now it is fixed.

Mailing list thread: http://lists.rpm.org/pipermail/rpm-list/2015-April/001740.html

Commit: https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/commit/c7fa7b2fd7205b73c833831ab9f8c311f40b2ff1

Answer (score 1):

RPM will ignore (by substituting newer version) older versions of identically named packages when installing. Either rename some of the packages, or don't install multiple versions of an identically named package in the same transactio

%pre failures when upgrading are tricky. The newer package will not install if %pre fails. and (on upgrade when there is an older version already installed) will remove the already installed package. The best answer here is don't rely on %pre failures in packaging while installing. Instead add Provides:/Requires:
so that the package (and transaction) failure occurs during dependency checking, or design a different means for testing a dynamic property than %pre,
either in configuration, or in documentation, or by renaming and obsoleteing the previous package to get a more reliable packaging.

Comment: I still don't understand why I get that problem only when I call `rpm -Uhv *.rpm` on all three files. If I do two consequtive updates 1->2 and 2->3, only the last operation fails and the package is not removed. As for the %pre section, in our project it performs a single transaction database update. If it fails, both dabatase and package itself are not updated.

Comment: RPM cannot do a multistage upgrade like 1->2 and then 2->3 in a single transaction. RPM uses the newest version (presumably 3) and skips the intermediate upgrade step. You can write %pre in the 3 package to perform intermediate upgrades with a loop. I'd still suggest avoiding %pre if at all possible.

Comment: Ok, but when I manually do update 1->3, it's still ok: package is not removed. It was an accident that I launched `rpm -Uhv` on all three packages. I suppose there shouldn't be any difference between `rpm -Uhv 1,3` and `rpm -Uhv 1,2,3`.

Comment: Was 1 installed originally or not? Both rpm -Uvh 1,3 and rpm -Uvh 1,2,3 install only the 3 package. RPM replaces multiple identically named packages with the newest version (3 in this case) and skips the older packages.

Comment: Yes, the first package was installed. Then I tried to update to the latest version and accidentally did `rpm -Uhv` on all three files.

Comment: Then you need to find out why rpm -Uvh 3 with 1 installed failed in %pre (contrary to what you have claimed). Yes if %pre 3 fails, and 1 was installed, then 1 will be removed. That is RPM behavior: good/bad/ugly.

Comment: I know why 3 fails. And when I do update 1->3, the package is not removed. Only the update fails. My package is removed **only** when I launch `rpm Uhv ` on all the files. Once again (assuming that 1 is installed before): `rpm Uhv 3` - package **is not** removed, `rpm -Uhv 1,2,3` - package **is** removed.

Comment: So you are concerned about different behaviors with buggy packaging? In the 1->3 fail case, the erase of 1 is scheduled by the 3 package and avoided by the %pre failure. In the 1->2->3 fail case, the erase is triggered by the 2 package which is replaced by the 3 package. The exit code from the %pre package is too late to attempt to unravel and reconstitute a transaction. Nor is it sufficient to return a FULLSTOP error: a buggy 3rd party script can block all system upgrades.